# Blink div border for X times?

Tags: jquery

I want when I click on a div, its border blink with blue color for say 5 times

Here what I've tried so far but it didn't work  http://jsfiddle.net/655yk/1/

```
 $("div").click(function () {
  $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
 });
```

and Html :

```
 <div style="border:1px solid ">Heki </div>
```

Comment: jquery has no effect method....

Comment: Should it blink with a different color, show/hide? Need more info

Comment: Try use `SetTimeOut` and toggle the `div` border..

Comment: why not use transition with CSS3?

Comment: @Madhu how do you toggle the border? You can place your answer here...

Comment: @C-link i didnt meant to use `toggle` method.. I mean just make the border to show and hide at a time interval..

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this, use setInterval

```
$("div").click(function () {
    var cnt = 0;
    $this = $(this);
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        cnt++
        if (cnt == 6) {
            $this.css('border', '1px solid');
            clearInterval(timer);
        } else {
            cnt % 2 == 1 ? $this.css('border', '1px solid red') : $this.css('border', '1px solid');
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/655yk/4/)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try something like this:

JS:

```
var colors = ['fc0000', '', 'fc0000', '', 'fc0000', '', 'fc0000', ''];

function animateBorder(element, x, time) {
    if (x >= colors.length) {
        x = 0;

    } else {
        x++;
        var color;
        if ( colors[x] === '' ) {
            color = ''
        } else {
            color = '#'+colors[x]
        }        
        element.css('border-color', color)
        setTimeout(function() {
            animateBorder(element, x, time);
        }, time)

    }
}


$('div').click(function() {
    var ele = $(this);
    var time = 500 //ms
    animateBorder(ele, 0, time);
})
```

I've created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/655yk/7/